# QPropertyAnimation doesn't work

Tags: qt

I'm trying to test animations in Qt desktop application. I just copied example from help. After button click, new button just appear in left top corner without animation (even end position is wrong). Am I missing something?

Qt 5.0.1, Linux Mint 64bit, GTK

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Animated Button", this);
    button->show();

    QPropertyAnimation animation(button, "geometry");
    animation.setDuration(10000);
    animation.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
    animation.setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

    animation.start();
}
```

Edit: Solved. Animation object must be as global reference. For example in section private QPropertyAnimation *animation. Then QPropertyAnimation = New(....);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just didn't copied the example, you also made some changes that broke it. Your `animation` variable is now a local variable that is destroyed at the end of `on_pushButton_clicked` function. Make the QPropertyAnimation instance a member variable of the MainWindow class and use it like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow), mAnimation(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPropertyAnimation animation
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete mAnimation;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Animated Button", this);
    button->show();

    mAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "geometry");
    mAnimation->setDuration(10000);
    mAnimation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
    mAnimation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

    mAnimation->start();
}
```

Comment: This solution is not good : each time you click on the button **pushButton** you will create an animation dynamically, when you close the application there will be at most one animation that is deleted as you delete the animation pointed by `mAnimation` in the destructor. So if you click many times there would be a memory leak. The best answer to the problem is the one mentioned by [@ville-lukka](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15584232/2775917)

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to make a slot specifically for deleting the `mAnimation` variable. Qt can do it for you if you use `QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped`:

```
QPropertyAnimation *mAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "geometry");
mAnimation->setDuration(10000);
mAnimation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
mAnimation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

mAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```